# Error in installing Azure tools in VS 2010

Tags: azure

I am trying to install Microsoft Azure tools in VS 2010 ultimate trial version in Windows 7 OS. But I am getting following error ::

Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

I have searched for this error alot but did not get appropriate solution. Somewhere I read that Microsoft Web Developer needs to be installed. I have installed it too but still getting the same error. can anyone help me with this error? Could you also provide me some link and guidelines..

Comment: Check your event logs, anything in there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Azure emulator?

See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719329/azure-tools-1-6-fail-to-install-and-show-a-weird-error-unless-azure-emulator-is-installed-first)

Comment: I have tried installing azure emulator..but still getting the same error.. Thank you for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing from the web platform installer?  That should install everything needed.

Comment: Yes. I am installing it from Web Platform Installer, but still getting the same error.  Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems installing it stand-alone, then downloaded the web platform installer and logged in on my admin account. Everything got installed correctly from there.

Comment: I am installing it from Web Platform Installer through my Admin Account but I am getting the same error.